# Active Directory Queries

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query, active-directory-group

This query:

```
(&(objectCategory=group)
(objectClass=group)
(description=Mandatory\20PIV\20Card\20Access\
20PROD\20\28this\20is\20for\20all\20PROD\20workstations\29))
```

currently gives the group.  I would like to access the members in the group and export the list.

Can anyone suggest how to go about doing so?

I am running this query from AD and I am seeking to obtain the members of the group from running this query and the not group.

Comment: Thank you for you prompt reply.  I am running this query from within AD.  Your edit to my Post still yields the group, but not the members in the group which is the result I am seeking.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your request should point on users and not on group :

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=MonGrp,OU=YourDomain,DC=local))
```

Where `CN=MonGrp,OU=YourDomain,DC=local` is the DN of the group you are interrested in.

You can point on the group like you do, but then the result is the `member` attribute of the object returned.